# how to count distinct value over two dimension using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset looks like the following. This dataset contains four variable Country name `Country`, company ID `Company`, `Year` and `Date`.

```
Country  Company  Year  Date 
-------  -------  ----  ----
A        1        2000     2000/01/02
A        1        2001     2001/01/03
A        1        2001     2001/07/02
A        1        2000     2001/08/03
B        2        2000     2001/08/03
C        3        2000     2001/08/03
```

I know how to count number of distinct company in each country. I did it using the following code.

```
proc sql;
   create table lib.count as
   select country, count(distinct company) as count 
   from lib.data
   group by country;
quit;
```

My problem is how to count the number of `distinct` company-Years in each country. Essentially i want to know how many different company or same company in different year. If there are two observation for the same company in the same year, I want to count it as 1 different value. If same company have two observation in differeny year I want to count it as two different value. I want the output looks like the following (one number per country):

```
Country  No. firm_year
A        2
B        1
C        1
```

Can anyone can teach me how to do it please.

Comment: Shouldn't your output dataset be A B C / 2 1 1 based on your input dataset? Where are you getting those values from?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  You are correct, I just made the number up

Comment: Why does A have 3 firm years? I only see two: 2000 and 2001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick method is to concatenate all the variables you want to compare, creating a new variable. Something like:

```
data data_mod;
    set data;
    length company_year $ 20;
    company_year= cats(company,year);
run;
```

Then you can run your `proc sql` with `count(distinct company_year)`.

Comment: If you prefer a more compact syntax you can add the middle-step as a sub-query of `proc sql`.

Answer (score 2):

You need nested queries, as @DaBigNikoladze hinted at...

- An "internal" query which will generate a list of distinct combinations of Country + Company + Year;
- An "external" query which will count how many rows per country are present in the internal query.

### Generate dataset

```
data have;
  informat Country $1.
           Company 1.
           Year 4.
           Date YYMMDD10.;
  format Date YYMMDDs10.;
  input country company year date;
  datalines;
A 1 2000 2000/01/02
A 1 2001 2001/01/03
A 1 2001 2001/07/02
A 1 2000 2001/08/03
B 2 2000 2001/08/03
C 3 2000 2001/08/03
;
```

### Execute query

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE want AS 
    SELECT country, Count(company) AS Firm_year 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT country, company, year FROM have) 
    GROUP  BY country; 
QUIT;
```

### Results

```
Country Firm_year 
A       2 
B       1 
C       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 proc sort data=lib.data out=temp nodupkey; 
   by country company year; 
 run;


 data firm_year(keep=country cnt_fyr);
   set out;
   by country company year
   retain cnt_fyr;
   if first.country then cnt_fyr=1;
   else cnt_fyr+1;
   if last.country;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your first question is:

```
data lib.count(keep=country companyCount);
   set lib.data;
   by country;
   retain companyList '';
   retain companyCount 0;
   if first.country then do;
      companyList = company;
      companyCount = 1;
   end;
   else do;
      if ^index(companyList, company) then do;
         companyList = cats(companyList,',',company);
         companyCount + 1;
      end;
   end;
   if last.country then output;
run;
```

The resutl is:

```
Country  companyCount
-------  ------------
A        2
B        1
C        1
```

Similary you will take the number of distinct company-Years in each country.

Answer (score 0):

Guess i'm a bit confused as to what you are expecting the result to look like. Here is an sql method that gets the same result as posted by the other answer so far.

```
data temp;
    attrib Country length = $10;
    attrib Company length = $10;
    attrib Year length = $10;
    attrib Date length = $10;
    input Country $ Company $ Year $ Date $;
    infile datalines delimiter = '@';
    datalines;
    A@1@x@x1@
    A@1@x@x2@
    B@2@x@x1@
    C@3@x@x3@
    ;
run;


proc sql;
   create table temp2  as
   select country,  count(distinct Date) as count 
   from temp
   group by country,  company;
quit;
```